# Sort a character vector based on an integer vector

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I am new to R so please excuse my basic question.
If I have 2 vectors like below:

```
v1 <- c("Italy", "US", "NY", "NY")
v2 <- c(3, 1, 2, 2)
```

I want to sort v1 to a vector like this with no duplicates:

```
v3 <- c("US", "NY", "Italy")
```

I tried the following code and it didn't work for me, I think it's because one is character the other is numerical:

```
sorted_v2 <- sort(v2)
#v2 is now 1, 2, 2, 3
v1[order(match(v1, sorted_v2))]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: What about `v1[v2]`?

Comment: `unique(v1[order(v2)])`

Comment: @Duck, this way it gave me ('NY', "Italy", "US", "US"), which works perfectly for another purpose just not in my case. Than you so much for your time!

Comment: @d.b, this worked wonderfully. Thank you so much!